# Android java How can I have a animation image move left and STAY there?

Tags: java, android

So basically I have this when you click on the image the image will move to the right but when the animation is done it will go back to the original position? How can I make it so it will stop at the spot it ends at in the animation? Here's my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="70%" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

This is my slide_in_right.xml

```
 public void sideBar()
   {


       ImageView sidebar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sidebar);

       mSlideInRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right);
       sidebar.startAnimation(mSlideInRight);


   }
```

And this is the code where it slides to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Animation` `setFillAfter(true)` method to persist the animation.

```
AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
alpha.setDuration(600);
alpha.setFillAfter(true);
```

Then

```
someView.startAnimation(alpha);
```

In your case, code should be

```
public void sideBar()
{
   ImageView sidebar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sidebar);

   mSlideInRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right);
   mSlideInRight.setFillAfter(true);
   sidebar.startAnimation(mSlideInRight);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a example on how I would add that to my code?

Comment: Yes, in your case `mSlideInRight.setFillAfter(true)`;
just before `sidebar.startAnimation(mSlideInRight)`;

Comment: Mhm, I added it and tested it with the code like this : http://pastebin.com/hC4zZzu1 And instead of doing my animation of moving it to the right instead it just faded out.

Comment: I gave my code of fading out. You should be using your old code with just one line addition - `mSlideInRight.setFillAfter(true)` after loading the animation through `AnimationUtils`

Comment: Question, How come It's not clickable in the new area? It's only still clickable in the area it was first at.

Comment: Not sure about this. May be the area it moves to was not clickable. I'm not sure if the view entirely moves to the new place or just its image.

Comment: Because I'm trying to make it where you can click it and it will slide out. and then you can click it again and it will slide back. Here's my code:http://pastebin.com/bXKvvxKN

Comment: It seems that at the beginning of the function you're setting `int out = 0;` So, can it ever be 1 when you call `sidebar()` again? Scope of `out` is local as it shows.

Comment: How could I fix it so I could make it do the animation pulling to the right and then when you click it again it will pull into the left?

Comment: May be by making `out` a member variable in your `Activity`

Comment: Okay, I did that. Now what it does it will shoot out the right animation and then instantly shoot in the left animation.

Comment: Make sure you have not called `sidebar()` twice. Do a bit of debugging and experiments.